# Rails 4 Populate production database with validated data for new users / display

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 - I don't want my users to come to the app with no data in it. I wish to give them sample validated data, which they can delete once they've seen how it all works.

I know about fixtures and seeding, Faker gem etc. And populating production database with development seed data.

Should I be looking to get my fixtures into the database for each new user? If so, how would I do that? Any general tips very welcome.

Comment: What about setting up a sample user with data and letting new users access the 'sample' user's account/data.

Comment: Yes OK, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the reply.